# GCP Vertex AI Rest API for Notebook Execution

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I'm a bit of a noob to Vertex AI.

I've made a user-managed notebook with a single Python3 notebook which does the work I need it to do.

My question is how can I call this notebook to run in Vertex AI from Python client? What would be the correct service(s) to call? The Vertex AI documentation is a little confusing. This basic use case or quickstart is difficult to locate.

Do I need to create a pipelines, then call that?

Thanks.

Comment: You can refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/start/client-libraries). Let me know if it's helpful or not?

Answer (score 1):

**Update Feb 15, 2023**

A python SDK for notebooks was released Jan 23, 2023: https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-notebooks/. Rob has the more complete answer.

**Original Answer from Aug 23, 2022**

Looking through the [Vertex SDK repo](https://github.com/googleapis/python-aiplatform/search?q=notebooks.googleapis&type=code), it doesn't look like the [Vertex AI Workbench API](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.executions/create) is supported. This means your options are either using the [UI](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/managed/executor) or trying the [generic Google python client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client).

Answer (score 1):

You can hit the rest API with the Python SDK. You'll want to use a managed notebook rather than a user-managed notebook. After running the executor (see managed notebooks docs), the notebook will end up in a bucket. You can then trigger the notebook via the API in a very handy way. I use the following pattern:

```
from google.auth import credentials

project='my_project'
location='us-central1'
notebook_instance='managed-notebook-my-notebook'

parent = f"projects/{project}/locations/{location}"


from google.cloud import notebooks_v1


client = notebooks_v1.NotebookServiceClient(credentials=service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('my_project-my_credentials.json'))

execution_obj = {

    "execution_template": {
        "scale_tier": "CUSTOM",
        "master_type": "n1-standard-64",
        "input_notebook_file": "gs://my_project-us-notebooks/executor_files/my_project.ipynb",
        "container_image_uri": "gcr.io/deeplearning-platform-release/tf-gpu.2-9",
        "output_notebook_folder": "gs://my_project-us-notebooks/executor_files/output",
        "parameters": "product_ids=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]", # you can parameterized variables with managed notebooks in Vertex.
        "service_account": "foobar@developer.gserviceaccount.com" # The email address of a service account to use when running the execution. You must have the iam.serviceAccounts.actAs permission for the specified service account.
    },
    "display_name": "TestExecution",
    "description": "Trying to execute notebook with API",
    "output_notebook_file": "gs://my_project-us-notebooks/executor_files/output/test_output_file.ipynb"

}
# Initialize request argument(s)
request = notebooks_v1.CreateExecutionRequest(
    parent=parent,
    execution_id="test1",
    execution=execution_obj
)

# Make the request
operation = client.create_execution(request=request)

print("Waiting for operation to complete...")

response = operation.result()

# Handle the response
print(response)
```